# Pell equation in ${\mathbb Q}(x)$

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations

Is it known whether the equation $A^2-(x^2+3)B^2=1$ has a solution $A,B\in{\mathbb Q}(x)$ with $B\neq 0$ ?

My thoughts : I think that there is no solution, as the fundamental solution of $A^2-(x^2+3)B^2=1$ for $x\in {\mathbb Z}$ seems to vary uncontrollably.

Comment: If the given equation is solvable, then it is also solvable for all $x \in \mathbb Q$. So if you want to show that there are no solutions, it might be possible to find two values of $x_1, x_2$ such that the resulting system of pell equations is not solvable. Systems of pell equations have been studied, so that might be an ansatz. PS: I think this question might also be worthy of being posted on mathoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \left( 2x^2 + 3 \right)^2 - \left( x^2 + 3 \right) \left( 2x \right)^2 = 9  $$
$$ \left( \frac{2}{3}x^2 + 1 \right)^2 - \left( x^2 + 3 \right) \left( \frac{2}{3}x \right)^2 = 1  $$

From $ \color{red}{\mbox{Jyrki's}} $ comment, material I had not realized applied here: we get a matrix that takes a solution ( as a column vector) to the next one, in matrix form 
$$
M =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{2}{3} x^2 + 1 & \frac{2}{3} x^3 + 2x \\
\frac{2}{3} x  & \frac{2}{3} x^2 + 1 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
In turn, we have solutions $(A_n, B_n)$ with $A_0 = 1, A_1 = \frac{2}{3} x^2 + 1,$ then $B_0 = 0, B_1 = \frac{2}{3} x,$ finally from Cayley-Hamilton
$$ A_{n+2} = \left(\frac{4}{3} x^2 + 2 \right) A_{n+1} - A_n $$ and
 $$ B_{n+2} = \left(\frac{4}{3} x^2 + 2 \right) B_{n+1} - B_n. $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

$$ \left( \frac{8}{163}x^2 + \frac{8}{163}x + \frac{165}{163} \right)^2 - \left( x^2 + x + 41 \right) \left( \frac{8}{163}x +  \frac{4}{163} \right)^2 = 1  $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

$$ \left( x^2 + \frac{k}{2} \right)^2 - \left( x^2 + k \right) \left( x \right)^2 = \frac{k^2}{4}  $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

$$ \left( x^2 + \frac{4k+1}{8} \right)^2 - \left( x^2 + x + k \right) \left( x + \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 = \frac{(4k-1)^2}{64}  $$
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

For these principal forms, we can always adjust by multiplying the appropriate terms by a rational constant to get $1$ on the right hand side, either $2/k$ or $8/(4k-1).$

Comment: Nice! I guess it's clear to all and sundry that if $(A,B)$ is one solution then we get infinitely many solutions with the usual recipe
$$(A+B\sqrt{x^2+3})^n=A_n+B_n\sqrt{x^2+3},$$
where $A_n,B_n\in\Bbb{Q}(x)$ and $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks. Good point about infinitely many solutions, that can also be written in my favorite method, a two by two matrix of polynomials that take an $(A,B)$ to the next one, in turn Cayley Hamilton takes that to two separate  linear recursions, $A_{n+2} = T A_{n+1} - A_n,$ another for $B_n,$ where $T$ is the trace of the two by two matrix and is a fixed polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

having trouble doing anything in the ring $\mathbb Q[x]$ for quartics. On the other hand, if you really meant the field of rational functions $\mathbb Q(x),$ we get an easy one. Given some $h(x)$ which could be a polynomial, take your favorite polynomials $f,g.$ Then
$$ \left(  \frac{h g^2 + f^2}{h g^2 - f^2} \right)^2 - h \cdot  \left(  \frac{2fg}{h g^2 - f^2} \right)^2 = 1 $$